# Where to use ngen.exe (Native Image Generator)?

Tags: c#

I have developed a winforms application, the application have one executable file (exe) and few dependencies library files (dll).

Now should I use ngen.exe command to the application file only

```
ngen install c:\app\app.exe
```

or exe with related all dlls?

```
ngen install c:\app\app.exe
ngen install c:\app\lib1.dll
ngen install c:\app\lib2.dll
```

Comment: the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ngen-exe-native-image-generator#actions) says 'Generate native images for an assembly and its dependencies' so i'd think you'll only need to target your .exe and ngen will detect and process the dependencies automatically

Comment: @D.J. As long as they're not loaded through reflection, of course. You'll need to manually specify any plugins or such. In any case, you should post that as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate native images for an assembly and its dependencies and install the images in the native image cache.

```
ngen install c:\app\app.exe
```